# Use pointer as a function's argument

Tags: go

How can I use methods of function arguments?

```
func writeToInflux(c interface{}, host string, service string, state string) bool {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(c), host, service)

    bp, e := client.NewBatchPoints(client.BatchPointsConfig{
        Database:  database,
        Precision: "us",
    })

    if e != nil {
        log.Print(e)
    }

    tags := map[string]string{
        "host":    host,
        "service": service,
    }

    fields := map[string]interface{}{
        "state": state,
    }

    pt, err := client.NewPoint("mon", tags, fields, time.Now())

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }

    bp.AddPoint(pt)

    if err := c.Write(bp); err != nil {
        log.Print("write failed " + err)
    }

    return true
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c, err := client.NewHTTPClient(client.HTTPConfig{
        Addr:     "http://10.x.x.x:8086",
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    a := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")
    writeToInflux(c, a[3], a[4], a[5])
}
```

In this example i can't use parameters of c variable, or maybe there is another options to use c as parameter to function?

Comment: Why is `c` in `writeToInflux` an `interface{}`? Do you need to pass multiple types to that function for some reason? If you make `c` the correct type, it will just work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"c" is an interface{} type, Having an interface in function parameter, you can able to pass any struct or any data types into it.

```
In your case you want c to use the function write
if err := c.Write(bp); err != nil {
        log.Print("write failed " + err)
    }
```

The compiler doesn't know the type of c, so you need to type assert it.

Try this, It will work

```
newC,ok:=  c.(type of c)    type of C -> a struct or any type which has a method write

if ok {
    if err := newC.Write(bp); err != nil {
            log.Print("write failed " + err)
        }

}
```

Or Change your function like this

```
func writeToInflux(c client.Client, host string, service string, state string) bool
```

Comment: I doubt this is the recommended approach. Its better to modify the function parameter to name an actual interface that implements write(). Use type assertion only if you actually benefit from the flexibility that interface{} offers.

Comment: I believe what @yazgazan has done is the better approach. Since the intention is to call a `Write` method on `c`, you would want to define an interface for it instead of using an empty interface and type asserting.

Answer (score 1):

In `writeToInflux`, the `c interface{}` doesn't specify any methods `c` should implement. You should use sine `InfluxWriter` interface so you can call `c.Write`:

```
type InfluxWriter {
    Write(bp client.BatchPoints) (*client.Response, error)
}
```

Alternatively, `writeToInflux` can accept a `client.Client`, giving you access to all its methods.

Comment: Maybe there is some posibility to pass c as argument with all it's methods?

Comment: Indeed there is :) Your `writeToInflux` can accept `c client.Client` in its arguments.

Comment: But there _is_ a benefit in passing an interface name: by doing that any type that implements the interface can be used, not just Client.

Comment: @FuzzyAmi The thing is (and I didn't notice it at first), OP is using `github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client/v2`, not `github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client`. This means `client.Client` is already an interface :)